# Is it OK invoke a methode in el expression but not for a action?

Tags: jsf-2, el

recently, I get some code like `rendered="#{bean.show()}"`. and it works. since jsf 2, we can do things like this, even in the js, like `if("#{bean.show()}) alert('I am here!');`

I want to know, what is the difference call a method or use a getter? Is there a performance issue?

thanks in advance

Liu

Answer (score 0):

Call method it means what you do action and handle response: do navigation for example.
Every field should have getter and setter for get data and set data from web page. If you have field for example

```
private String username;
```

you should have also getter and setter, and get/set value with that method according java requirements,you cant have

```
public String username 
//never do this
```

and access field directly.

also getter/setter does not connect with performance, till your code is correct.

You should review java core part and also JSF tutorial
[JSF tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/index.htm)

Comment: I know the difference between the action method and the setter/getter. I want to know if there is a difference between 'rendered="#{bean.isShowMe()}"' and 'rendered="#{bean.showMe}"' when execute.

Comment: Difference is what #{bean.isShowMe()} does not work under Apache Tomcat 6 and with JSF/JSP old releases, for example with JSF 1.2, started from JSF2 #{bean.isShowMe()} and #{bean.isShowMe} the same! In actions with #{bean.isShowMe(list.id)} you can pass params directly to managed bean method!(JSF2)